# Aspose PDF accept method throwing StackOverflow error

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, java-11, aspose, aspose.pdf

We have built a Spring boot application which has endpoints for document operations. One of the end point tries to find text in PDF using Aspose-PDF API. When we try to find text in a PDF document of size 20 MB with more than 200 pages using regex "(<<.*?>>)|(<<(.|\R)*?>>)" the application is taking long time to process and the request is eventually failing with StackOverflow error. The boot application is running on Windows Server with JDK 11.0.21.

We tried to execute the same application as standalone with Main method in the same Windows server, it is working fine. Also, if the same application is executed as boot in local machine the same code is working fine. Can anyone advise.

Comment: Have you tried to investigate if any other application routine is causing this delay? Can you please create a post in Aspose.PDF dedicated [support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) which is the right place to discuss such issues and you can also have proper follow up on the progress against issue there. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.